# Bash Scripting - Exiting While Loop When User Input = "done"

Tags: bash

How do you exit a while loop in bash when user input detects "done"?

The objective is to have users input restaurant names and when they type done, the while loop escapes and and it randomly spits out a random restaurant within the array? As of right now, it only escapes when CTRL + D but this also closes the terminal

P.S: I've only been playing with bash for about 2 hours!

```
echo 'Where are you having trouble deciding? Type done to finish'

while read restaurants
do
  rest_array=("${rest_array[@]}" $restaurants)
done


echo Eat at ${rest_array[$rand]}
```

Comment: Use the `break` command to exit any loop.

Comment: `rest_array+=("$restaurants")` is a simpler way to append to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Use **break** to exit the loop in bash

```
echo 'Where are you having trouble deciding? Type done to finish'

while read restaurants
do
  if [[ "$restaurants" == "done" ]]; then
     break
  fi
  rest_array+=("$restaurants")
done


echo Eat at ${rest_array[$rand]}
```

Comment: I tried this way but it closes out of the script completely (using WIN10)

Comment: What kind of shell are you using?

Comment: Using bash, file name randomrest.sh

Comment: It's strange. Can you explain "it closes out of the script completely" please?

Comment: Sure. When I open the script (double clicking the script file), I input relevant texts, and once I type done then enter, the bash window just closes as if I type CTRL + D or X out the window. I hope I'm describing it properly

Comment: That has nothing to do with `bash`; your system is configured to close the window when the process running the script completes. It's probably too fast to notice, but the last `echo` is executed first. Add something like `sleep 10` to the end of your script to make it more obvious.

Comment: Ok, that's not a bash issue, but a terminal one. Add a "sleep 2" at the end of the script, or a "read", to let you read the result

Comment: Thank you both! It worked! Excuse my silly questions, I'm very new to bash scripting. Have a great day!!

Comment: You are welcome. Have a great time in bash scripting!